# Javascript: How to concatenate 2 values treating undefined or null values as empty

Tags: javascript

This is what I want:

```
var str = data + unit; // data:"2", unit: "rem", I want str: "223"
var str = data + unit; // data:"2", unit: null, I want  str: "2"
var str = data + unit; // data:"2", unit: undefined, I want  str: "2"
var str = data + unit; // data:undefined, unit: "rem", I want str: "rem"
```

Input and output values are given in the comments against each line. Normal concatenation appends "undefined" as a literal string. I want undefined and null values to be treated as empty string

Comment: What are the values?

Comment: @iota They're given in the comment against each line

Comment: Are those strings or objects?

Comment: @iota They're strings. I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: `var str = (data != null ? data : '') + (unit != null ? unit : '');` (ES5 compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the nullish coalescing operator to convert null or undefined to an empty string.

```
var str = (data ?? "") + (unit ?? "");
```

For better browser support, you may want to use the logical or operator instead.

```
var str = (data || "") + (unit || "");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function

```
const checkValue = value => value ? value :  '';
console.log(checkValue(null) + checkValue(null)) // ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the unit before concatenation.
If its value is either undefined or null set it to empty, or whatever you want.
Then you can concatenate.

```
function concatenate(data, unit) {
    if(unit == undefined || unit == null) {
        unit = "";
    }
    return data + " " + unit;
}
```